# Browser support for left: 0; right: 0;

Tags: html, css

Pretty much as per the title really.

Is it safe to use the following CSS to make the element fit to its parent's width?

```
.element {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

We can ignore IE < 8.

Comment: What kind of answer would you like to get here? Obviously the standard says that this will work, so are you after empirical evidence that some particular browser does not honor it? Possibly under specific circumstances?

Comment: Will work in all used browsers except IE6 (will not work in IE7 if you don't have a proper doctype). So you should be fine.

Comment: @Jon e.g. IE6 could not handle this kind of positioning. So it is a valid question I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is safe. But don't hold me to it. This statement is provided as is, without warranty of any kind.

Here's a nice article: [Conflicting Absolute Positions](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/conflictingabsolutepositions/)

Also, the parent needs to have position applied (i.e. other than `static`, usually `relative`).

Answer (score 2):

`left` and `right` are completely supported by all major  browsers

[image]

The value  `inherit`  is not supported in **IE7** and **earlier**.

Comment: sure, but to be precise the question was about not `(left || right)` but `(left && right)`. But nontheless this is supported in all browsers from IE8 on, so the OP is save (it would fail in IE6 though...).